# How to Change Character from "." to "|" Between Portfolio Categories in WordPress Website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, portfolio, web-inspector

[Link To Website Page](http://gatewaywebdesign.com/portfolio/)

A kind of ridiculous request, but I need to change the small dot in-between "Graphic Design" and "Website Design" to a vertical bar "|". I assumed that I'd be able to make this change in portfolios.php, but I can't seem to find the dot anywhere in the file. In the inspector, you can see that the dot lies in-between the Graphic Design and Website Design links:

[image]

Which brings me to another question - does the inspector not tell you where the highlighted portion of the HTML is coming from (what PHP file)? For example, you can always see what file is responsible for the styles that are applied to the selected element in the inspector, but you can't seem to find the PHP files that are responsible for creating the highlighted portion of the HTML. Since I didn't find the dot "." in portfolio.php, I'm assuming that it's somewhere else but I don't really know where else to look.

[image]

But I did find the class "my_term-archive" in [portfolio.php](http://pastebin.com/NnMJUMat) - you can see that it falls within an If, ForEach statement in the file. The point of the portfolio is to allow viewers to toggle back and forth in-between Graphic Design and Website design categories. Each portfolio item is marked as either a "Graphic Design" or "Website Design" category in WordPress's backend. It looks like the portfolio was created with the Codenovo Portfolio Plugin but I'm not really sure - it doesn't show up as a plugin in the dashboard and I didn't develop this site myself.

Thanks for any help that you can give!

Comment: "Which brings me to another question - does the inspector not tell where the highlighted portion of the HTML is coming from (what PHP file)?" No, it has no clue what PHP files are behind the scenes. It just sees the HTML.

Comment: That's too bad. You'd think that Google / Safari / Firefox would include that feature to make it easier on developers.

Comment: It would be technologically impossible to do that.

Comment: care to explain why? I'd accept your comment as an answer since it was a part of my original question.

Comment: The resulting HTML on a page gives no indication of what PHP file it originates from. Take this example: https://gist.github.com/ceejayoz/d368ee9cb4783e1d82f106d1d17f27a5 - visiting `index.php` would output simply `<h1>Hello!</h1>` to the browser, yet four files are involved, and the output itself comes from `four.php`.

Comment: Why wouldn't visiting index.php output two.php or <?php include('two.php'); ?>  ?

Comment: Because PHP is evaluated server side and PHP code does not get output unless it explicitly outputs something.  The `include` is replaced by whatever content is output by the include.  And again, since it's server side and no metadata about this is sent to the browser, it has no idea about what files and code ran, nor that it was even from PHP.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot is a unicode character called "middle dot" - it's html entity name is

```
&middot;
```

Just as there's an html entity name for the middle dot unicode character, there's also an html entity name for the vertical line unicode character:

(decimal)

```
&#124;
```

(hex)

```
&#x7c;
```

Information on both can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm) and [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7c/index.htm). There are [many more unicode characters](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0D10), each with unique HTML codes.

Answer (score 2):

The dot separator does appear to be coming from the template you posted.  It's represented as `$term_list .= ' &middot; ';` on line 30.

Comment: Yeah I also noticed ' &middot; ' - it looks like it can be used instead of a bullet in a ul. But then what's the list style type / property used for a vertical line "|" ?

Comment: It's "&#124;" see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7c/index.htm